# Magento 2 get custom cache value in block

Tags: php, magento2, magento2.2

I have created a custom cache in a custom module to which I am able to read and write through an observer. However, when I'm trying to get the stored data in a block file I am getting an empty response.

Here is my code:

**Block/Calendar.php**

```
namespace Myextension\Functionality\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Cache;

class Calendar extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $cache;

    public function __construct(Template\Context $context,\Magento\Framework\App\Cache $cache, array $data = array())
        {
            parent::__construct($context, $data);

            // set constructor values
            $this->cache = $cache;

        }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCountriesList()
    {
        $stores_cache = unserialize($this->cache->load("STORES_CACHE_TAG"));

        return $stores_cache;
    }
}
```

And here is the observer which is able to read/write to the cache successfully.

```
namespace Myextension\Functionality\Observer\Adminhtml;

class CacheRefreshType implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $cache;
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * CacheRefreshType constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache $cache,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {

        // set constuct variables
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->cache = $cache;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    private function refreshStoresCache() {

        // get list of stores
        $storeManagerDataList = $this->storeManager->getWebsites();

        // init empty array of stores
        $stores = [];

        // for each store
        foreach ($storeManagerDataList as $key => $value) {
            // append store information
            $stores[$key] = [
                "label" => $value["name"],
                "code"=>$value["code"]
            ];
        }


        // save cache
        $this->cache->save(serialize($stores), "stores_cache_tag",array("STORES_CACHE_TAG"), 99999);

        $stores_cache = unserialize($this->cache->load("STORES_CACHE_TAG"));

    }
```

I am really thankful for any help!